# Receive Drops and Receive Overrun Errors counters on an Openflow Port

Tags: openflow

In the Openflow 1.3.3 spec you have the Receive Dropped and Receive Overrun Errors counters for a port. What are the conditions when these 2 counters increment?

Thanks

Comment: Did the answer bellow helped?

Answer (score 0):

Receive Overrun Errors: This warning is is related to load on the COM port and the CPUs ability to service the COM port interrupts (ie. CPU load and interrupt priorities).

Receive Dropped: I think this increments when a switch receives a packet but it drops. In other words, it receives a packet but it doesn't forward it to any of it port.

**Edit**:
Here is what I think:

Note that there is 2 Received Packets counter.

1. Received Packets Per Flow Entry. So it is incremented when a packet is received and it is matched to that flow.
2. Received Packets Per Port: This one doesn't care what flow it is going to match with. If a packet is received in a port, increment it.

Receive Dropped is per port. So Receive Dropped should always be less than or equal to Received Packets.

Comment: Thanks. In the case of Receive Dropped do you know what is the reason the port drops the packet? Buffer overflow?

Comment: I am not sure about the reason, but I know there could two way to drop a packet.
1. A flow says drop some specific packet 
2. A buffer overflow, or CPU can't keep up.




I think some switches act as a firewall too. So they might a drop a packet if they think the packet is fishy.

Comment: I would expect the counters for a flow dropping packets to be in that flow's stats rather than at port level. Is the receiveDropped counter included in the receivePackets counter?

Comment: Here is what I think: 

Note that there is 2 Received Packets  counter. 
1. Received Packets Per Flow Entry. So it is incremented  when a packet is received and it is matched to that flow. 

2. Received Packets Per Port: This one doesn't care what flow it is going to match with. If a packet is received in a port, increment it. 

Receive Dropped is per port. So Receive Dropped should always be less than or equal to Received Packets.